# Altering time-step creates Layer error

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have written the following code to calculate the number of pixel classified as water within my region of interest.

I am manually adjusting the dates repeatedly to get a time series of flooded area/lake size i.e I am reading off the calculated "object" value and recording it in an excel file. My code has worked perfectly for 2019, 2018 and most of 2017 but fails for the years 2016 and 2015. I get this error:

```
Layer 1: Layer error: Image.lte: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1.
```

Does anybody know how I fix this??

My code is as below:

```
//I am trying to construct a time series of flood extent over the duration of a whole year. The code will then be edited to be replicated for previous years as well


//This does all that I want.
//When you press run it will spit out two object values. The top one is the number of water pixles. The bottom value is the area classifiied as water
//Record these in excel spreadsheet.
//To get the next time step i need to go through and change the code each time i.e do this for each month, and then also for each year.
//So i need to change it all manually, rather than the code working it all out at for me

// Load Sentinel-1 C-band SAR Ground Range collection (log scale, VH, descending)
var collectionVH = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
.filterMetadata('resolution_meters', 'equals' , 10)
.filterBounds(roi)
.filter(ee.Filter.date('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31'))
.select('VH');
print(collectionVH, 'Collection VH');

//filter the date for the first half of january

var Jan1 = collectionVH.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2015-01-15').mean();

//smooth image to remove error
var SMOOTHING_RADIUS = 100;
var Jan1filtered = Jan1.focal_mean(SMOOTHING_RADIUS, 'circle', 'meters');


//mask image to just get water. This is using high certainity water mask
var Jan1mask = Jan1filtered.updateMask(Jan1filtered.lte(-23));

//map this layer

Map.addLayer(Jan1mask,{palette:"00FFFF"});

//The next step calculated the number of pixles classified as water (i.e they had a value of 1 rather than 0? Or 0 rather than 1, need to check)
// Sum the values of water pixels in the ROI. I did this one at a time and deletedthe old one after each step to save room i.e its been repeated over and over
var stats = Jan1mask.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(stats);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot run your script without modifying it, so I cannot be 100% sure what's going on - always try to provide a link to a working script with all your used assets shared - but this is an error you typically get when you try to do operations on an image without bands.

```
var Jan1 = collectionVH.filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-01-15').mean();
print('Number of images', collectionVH.filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-01-15').size())
print('Jan1', Jan1)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a54e2efec4acc57f34260cec0c2cffb

Here, you have no images in the date range. Calling `mean()` on an empty collection gives you an image without bands. When performing operations on this image give you the error you see.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right. I've been told that sentinel VH polarisation doesnt go back to 2015, hence there being no image.

Comment: Hi @skinerdean. If Daniel's answer satisfies your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark underneath the vote tally for this answer. Accepting useful answers helps keep the "google-earth-engine" tag tidy (removes questions from the list of unanswered questions) and is a nice acknowledgment for those answering questions. Thanks - best regards.